# Java-MySQL-Android: bad base-64

Tags: java, php, android, base64

I guess this is a stupid question with an obvious solution, but I don't see it yet. So the problem is: I get an `IllegalArgumentException` on Android, which says my base64 input is not valid. This input took the following way before:

Upload: PDF file -(Java Base64 encoder) > Java Base64 encoded string -(POST)-> PHP -(INSERT as mediumtext via mysqli query)-> MySQL DB

Download: MySQL record -(SELECT via mysqli query and fetch assoc afterwards)-> PHP vars -(JSON)-> Java as JSON -(Jackson library, maps JSON to object containing String)-> Java Base64 String - (Android Base64 decoder)-> Exception

Is there any failure in my workflow? Communication is done with UTF-8 via `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: 1.  Check that there are only valid Base64 characters in the file.  2. Is the decoding end expecting the "=" padding at the end, and if so is it present?  Some Base64 implementations omit it.

Comment: Thank you! "Unfortunately" both conditions are already met. At least when uploading. But in the string, which Android tries to decode, there are no + and each / is replaced by \/

Comment: How much control do you have over the initial encoding?  If '/' is giving problems then perhaps you need to change to URL-safe Base64 instead.  Alternatively, do you need to change the way you store the Base64 text in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem: During transfer to the server + and / got omitted. After manually replacing them, everything is working now.